# Can't upload images on chat anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, images

Since i.imgur.com doesn't allow cross-linking anymore, we can't upload images.

Well, we can upload them, but it's useless since they're not oneboxed.

Example: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/18249353#18249353

Comment: we can upload images they just are not oneboxed proper

Comment: I've been able to successfully upload images, it's just getting them to onebox in chat that's the problem. It's weird, because some of the time it works, and some of the time it doesn't.

Comment: it also appears the issue [is just with the chat system](http://jsbin.com/wequta/1/edit) and not imgur blocking external links.

Comment: Is there anything the dev team can do about it, except to contact the imgur dev team?

Comment: An "extreme" idea could be to change image "provider" altogether.

Comment: This looks like corrupted thumbnails, which I think imgur creates for us (and something we just recently started using); pinging the resident chat expert.

Comment: Now re-enabled (see update)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Jarrod correctly notes, this appears to be a bug at the imgur thumbnailing process - completely without any evidence I'm going to blindly speculate that it is a race condition where we are requesting the thumbnail **immediately** after upload, since I can't repro it if I space out the upload and thumnbail request.

I will disable the thumbnails for now, while I investigate.

---

Update: imgur have very kindly made some changes at their end; thumbnails are now re-enabled, with some extra tweaks too:

- outputs protocol-relative links
- works for all i(.*).imgur domains, not just i.stack.imgur.com
- detects and handles any existing thumbnail suffix on the url

Comment: Thanks! Great to see you working on it :)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine it is disabled for now

Comment: @MarcGravell I appreciate very much your work adding this feature and am sorry that it has caused an inconvenience for other users due to that bug. Hope imgur can take action and have it fixed.

Comment: @Prix me too! it is a good feature, if it works

Comment: @MarcGravell would it be possible for you to make the opposite? If the image was posted as the smaller version on the chat, change the link to the bigger size as it would not break anything? But to any image hosted on imgur instead of just stack.imgur? This way I can have my own gallery and post the smaller image which would be automatically linked to their respective original size when clicked

Comment: So what you mean is: any link to `...blah/([0-9a-zA-Z]{5})[stbmlh]?\.` should use $1m as the thumbnail and $1 as the link? sure, yes. I should also make both thumbnail and link protocol-relative at the same time, since we know imgur is ok with that (other providers may not be, so we should preserve the protocol of the supplied image)

Comment: @MarcGravell because I plan on using my own imgur account to upload images to my gallery, then if I post this image http://i.imgur.com/t0wj1Gkm.jpg it would link to its normal size like this `[http://i.imgur.com/t0wj1Gkm.jpg](http://i.imgur.com/t0wj1Gk.jpg)` hence the "url destination" would have the M removed from it. ***So yes $1m as thumb and $1 as link and that would not break the upload or viewing images :)***

Comment: @MarcGravell just for imgur but not limited to the i.stack.imgur address if possible, let me know and once again thx for the feedback ;)

Comment: @prix sounds reasonable

Comment: @Prix try now; should work

Comment: @MarcGravell awesome its working just fine, thanks a lot. I did like to take this opportunity and ask you what would be required to have this question feature implemented(if you could give me a rough idea would be enough)? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232072/myanimelist-onebox-for-animemanga-chat

Comment: @MarcGravell nice tweaks very nice they took the time to investigate the issue and improve it.

Comment: @MarcGravell [the upload seems to be not functional yet with thumbnails gave me a 404 aside from that posting images already uploaded work just fine](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17179761#17179761)

Comment: it seems imgur still have a slight race condition issue? Some images have seems to be breaking the thumbnail on a very rare case basis.

Comment: @Prix any examples?

Comment: @MarcGravell This one http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17181937#17181937 and http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17181933#17181933 I think the later was the one I used the upload on, but this happens on a very rare basis, I've been uploading lots of image along the day and that was the only one that failed. On the chat they are being shown as not found on the thumbnail.

Comment: I'm still reproducing this bug: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2327360#2327360, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/18377300#18377300. Though it strangely worked here: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2327384#2327384.

Comment: @hichris imgur are investigating a possible cdn caching issue here

Comment: Ah, I'm glad this is already being discussed. This has been winding me up no end for the past couple of days!